# Setting UIImageView Width, Height, Aspect Ratio & Constraints X, Y

Tags: swift, uiimageview, constraints

I've set a UIImageView in my view controller and assigned constraints x & Y which works I'm trying to set the image width, height & aspect ratio but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried many answers already on here but can seem to get it working.

```
import UIKit

class GuestLoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let headerImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setHeaderImage()
    }

    func setHeaderImage() {
        view.addSubview(headerImage)
        headerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: super.view.frame.width, height: 95)
        headerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        headerImage.mask?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.redraw
        headerImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headerImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        headerImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "header")
        view.sendSubviewToBack(headerImage)
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try to change this line before the last line?
 headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "header")
 view.addSubview(headerImage)
view.sendSubviewToBack(headerImage)
or you can call 
headerImage.setNeedsLayout()

Comment: @ValNolav I already have view.addSubview(headerImage) it's the first line in my function. I moved it after the headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "header") line but I then get error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: It is because of constraints line you are adding. You need to move view.addSubview(headerImage) above adding constraints line
    headerImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: @ValNolav still doesn't work even if move the line above the constraints or remove the constraints line the image is too big / height. 

https://imgur.com/a/M3ZatHA

Comment: headerImage.mask?.contentMode =  .scaleAspectFit 
can you try this?

Comment: @ValNolav still the same result.

Comment: As soon as you set `headerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, the `frame` is ignored.  You need to set some constraint to establish the height of your `UIImageView`.  Unfortunately, the `image` contents does not affect the height of the `UIImageView`.  Set either 1) an absolute height constraint, 2) an offset from the bottom of the superView, 3) height relative to the width with a multiplier (an "aspect ratio constraint").

Comment: @vacawama yes, that has fixed it! I've removed the ```headerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false``` line and it works perfectly. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you set `headerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, the `frame` is ignored. You need to set some constraint to establish the height of your `UIImageView`. Unfortunately, the image contents does not affect the height of the `UIImageView`.

Set either:

1. an absolute height constraint
2. an offset from the bottom of the superView
3. height relative to the width with a multiplier (an "aspect ratio constraint")

Based on my comment, you turned off `headerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and it worked.

This gives you extra constraints (your 3 plus the 4 that are generated from the frame), but luckily they aren't conflicting.

Instead, I would suggest you leave the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false` and set a constraint for the `height`:

```
headerImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95).isActive = true
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense now. I thought ```headerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: super.view.frame.width, height: 195)``` was setting the height. I didn't know that I had to set the constraint height too.